# Extract and use a part of string with a regex in GVIM

Tags: regex, vim

I've got a string:

```
doCall(valA, val.valB);
```

Using a regex in GVIM I would like to change this to:

```
valA = doCall(valA, val.valB);
```

How would I go about doing this? I use `%s` for basic regex search and replace in GVIM, but this a bit different from my normal usages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
%s/\vdoCall\(<(\w*)>,/\1 = doCall(\1,/
```

`\v` enables “more magic” in regular expressions – not strictly necessary here but I usually use it to make the expressions simpler. `<…>` matches word boundaries and the in-between part matches the first parameter and puts it in the first capture group. The replacement uses `\1` to access that capture group and insert into the right two places.

Comment: My actual use case was subtly different 

doCall(valA, val.valB);

- your answer above is working great for my initial question, but not with the extra . it's not working.

Comment: @André: It definitely should work, unless the dot appears in the *first* argument. In that case you need to adapt `\w` accordingly, e.g. write `\w|\.` to also allow a dot, **and** remove the less-than and greater-than signs.